# cloning from linux to a windows virtualbox results in an incomplete repo on vm

Tags: git, clone, virtualbox

I am running Oricle VirtualBox in fedora 20. I am trying to clone a repository vm with Windows XP for testing web apps against IE.

I shared the folder and ran the command: git clone E:\weewikipaint weewikipaint from C:\projects directory. I get the directory C:\projects\weewikipaint but not all the files from my linux repository are cloned over to the windows vm. Specifically I am missing the .git file and a /build directory. Interestingly, it is picking other hidden directories, directories, and hidden files.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: windows command window with commands I issued]

[image: Linux command window showing missing files]

Comment: I changed the question to be more explicitly about testing code. Also, Git is pretty "commonly used by programmers." Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `.git` isn't hidden itself:

```
cd weewikipaint
dir /AH
```

If any git command is working within `weewikipaint/`, that should mean it is a valid git repo.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330833/user3330833) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454092/cloning-from-linux-to-a-windows-virtualbox-results-in-an-incomplete-repo-on-vm/26459453#comment41575985_26459453) it was a `.gitignore` issue
(which you can check with a `git check-ignore -v -- afile`)

> I had build in a `.gitignore` in my `/home`

Comment: dir /AH did show that the .git file is in fact hidden...still not understanding the absence of the /build dir.

Comment: @user3330833 what the build dir versioned in the first repo, or was it ignored? What (in the first repo) would return a `git check-ignore -v build`? (assuming you are using the latest msysgit 1.9.4)

Comment: Bingo! And newb alert! I had build in a .gitignore in my /home...Thanks!

Comment: @user3330833 Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.